# why is my program crashing while using this loop structure?

Tags: python, debugging, syntax-error

program keeps crashing and I can't figure out the bugs or what's causing it to crash

this is what I have, please tell me what I'm missing

```
STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.6
CITY_TAX_RATE = 0.2

totalTax = itemPrice * STATE_TAX_RATE + itemPrice * CITY_TAX_RATE

totalPrice = itemPrice + totalTax

itemPrice = float(input("Enter price: "))

print("Item price is " + str(itemPrice) + " and total tax is " + str(totalTax))
print("Total price is " + str(totalTax))
```

Comment: There are no loops here, though there is an error: `itemPrice` should be assigned *above* the `totalTax` and `totalPrice` lines

Answer (score 0):

see is this works

note order of itemPrice

```
STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.6
CITY_TAX_RATE = 0.2
itemPrice = float(input("Enter price: "))
totalTax = itemPrice * STATE_TAX_RATE + itemPrice * CITY_TAX_RATE

totalPrice = itemPrice + totalTax

print("Item price is " + str(itemPrice) + " and total tax is " + str(totalTax))
print("Total price is " + str(totalTax))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop here. Reordering your code as shown below will fix your issue:

```
STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.6
CITY_TAX_RATE = 0.2

itemPrice = float(input("Enter price: "))

totalTax = itemPrice * STATE_TAX_RATE + itemPrice * CITY_TAX_RATE

totalPrice = itemPrice + totalTax


print("Item price is " + str(itemPrice) + " and total tax is " + str(totalTax))
print("Total price is " + str(totalTax))
```

Answer (score 0):

NameError: name 'itemPrice' is not defined

This is the error you get because you have assigned itemPrice after the calculation (where it is needed), so you get a NameError

By reordering the code by writing

```
itemPrice = float(input("Enter price: "))
```

before the calculation of totalTax, your error should be fixed

full correct code -

```
STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.6
CITY_TAX_RATE = 0.2

itemPrice = float(input("Enter price: "))
''' now it is assigned first so it will indeed carry out the calculation 
afterwards without any errors '''

totalTax = itemPrice * STATE_TAX_RATE + itemPrice * CITY_TAX_RATE

totalPrice = itemPrice + totalTax

print("Item price is " + str(itemPrice) + " and total tax is " + 
str(totalTax))
print("Total price is " + str(totalTax))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an undefined variable. Move line `itemPrice = ...` higher, so it's before any usages of `itemPrice` variable.

By the way, there's no loop here.

Full code:

```py
STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.6
CITY_TAX_RATE = 0.2

itemPrice = float(input("Enter price: "))

totalTax = itemPrice * STATE_TAX_RATE + itemPrice * CITY_TAX_RATE

totalPrice = itemPrice + totalTax

print("Item price is " + str(itemPrice) + " and total tax is " + str(totalTax))
print("Total price is " + str(totalTax))
```